# Stripe Checkout: moving from Node to Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

My Angular 11 app uses [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=checkout&ui=checkout) with an Express server to handle the payment.  Everything works fine with Angular & Node. I'd like to use Firebase Functions instead of Node, but when I call my Firebase Function, I get the error:

> IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.

**Angular code**:

```
checkout(): void {
    var stripe = Stripe(environment.stripe.key);

    var productName = 'T-shirt!!';
    var price = '2000';

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            productName: productName,
            price: price
        })
    };
    var url = 'http://localhost:4242/create-checkout-session';                      // Node server
    //var url = 'http://localhost:5000/MY_FIREBASE_PROJECT/us-central1/stripeTest'; // Firebase emulation
    fetch(url, options)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
            return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {                                                    // redirect fails due to browser or network error
                alert(result.error.message);
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
}
```

**Node server**:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const stripe = require('stripe')('MY_SECRET_KEY')
const port = 4242;

app.use(express.json())                                                          // parse request body as JSON

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');       // website you wish to allow to connect
    // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');                                                                            // request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');             
    next();                                                                      // pass to next layer of middleware
});

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
    var productName = req.body.productName;
    var price = req.body.price;

    console.log('body = ', req.body);
    console.log('price = ', req.body.price);

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
            {
                price_data: {
                    currency: 'usd',
                    product_data: {
                        name: productName,
                    },
                    unit_amount: price,
                },
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: 'http://localhost:4200/home?action=success',
        cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4200/home?action=cancel',
    });

    res.json({ id: session.id });
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '!'));
```

**Firebase Function**:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('MY_SECRET_KEY')
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.stripeTest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    var productName = data['productName'];
    var price = data['price'];
    console.log('data: ', data);
    console.log('product name = ', productName);
    console.log('price = ', price);

    const session = stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
            {
                price_data: {
                    currency: 'usd',
                    product_data: {
                        name: productName,
                    },
                    unit_amount: price,
                },
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: 'http://localhost:4200/home?action=success',
        cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4200/home?action=cancel',
    }, async (err, data) => {});

    return { id: session.id };
})
```

I don't understand the issue because I pass in `line_items`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping me get here.

When using Firebase Functions, you need to make your call from Angular with `httpsCallable` instead of `fetch`...

**Angular code**:

```
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

constructor(
    // ...
    private afFun: AngularFireFunctions) {

    afFun.useEmulator("localhost", 5000);
}

checkoutFirebase(): void {
    var stripe = Stripe(environment.stripe.key);
    this.afFun.httpsCallable("stripeTest")({ productName: 'T-shirt', price: '400' })
        .subscribe(result => {           // the result is your Stripe sessionId
            console.log({result});       

            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: result,
            }).then(function (result) {
                console.log(result.error.message);
            });
        });
}
```

Then we need to add `async` to the `onCall` in Firebase.

**Firebase Function**:

```
exports.stripeTest = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    var productName = data['productName'];
    var price = data['price'];

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
            {
                price_data: {
                    currency: 'usd',
                    product_data: {
                        name: productName,
                    },
                    unit_amount: price,
                },
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: 'http://localhost:4200/home?action=success',
        cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4200/home?action=cancel',
    });

    return session.id;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`session.id` is `typeof 'undefined'`, as the error message hints for.
Which means, that it would have to be passed into the function along with `data` (there are no server-side sessions available).

Also verify the property names, because at least `line_items` is unknown to Stripe API.

Comment: Also `"line_items" !== "lineItems"`

Comment: Indeed, I didn't read that closely... but was only trying to make sense out of the error message. It's `.redirectToCheckout()`, where `sessionId` is the only property being passed - so there is not much space for alternate causes.

Comment: I tried swapping 'line_items' to 'lineItems', but it gives the same error. plus, 'line_items' works in the Node code, and that's directly from Stripe's documentation

Answer (score 0):

Rebounding Ryan Loggerythm's updated answer.

After about half an hour or so of fiddling with Stripe's docs solutions (which seem more geared towards getting devs to try out the demo instead of actually implementing the technology) and other guides on Medium, I loaded up your updated answer and lo and behold it worked *absolutely flawlessly* and all that within 2 paragraphs, 1 for Angular, 1 for Firebase functions, hence the whole point of using Stripe's Checkout product instead of making our own checkout (or turning towards Shopify's): turnkey simplicity.

Meanwhile Stripe's API docs felt like a maze for this simple solution. Maybe Ryan should be the one making Stripe's documentation